# SQL server SUM of MAX in different columns for each item

Tags: sql, sum, max

```
+---------+--------+-----+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
| Quot_ID | Art_ID | Qty | Qty_Alt | Price | Price_Alt | Value | Value_Alt | Status |
+---------+--------+-----+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
| 1000000 | 100000 |  10 |       0 |   100 |         0 |  1000 |         0 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 100000 |   0 |      20 |     0 |        90 |     0 |      1800 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 100000 |   0 |      30 |     0 |        80 |     0 |      2400 | won    |
| 1000000 | 100000 |   0 |      40 |     0 |        70 |     0 |      2800 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 200000 |  10 |       0 |   150 |         0 |  1500 |         0 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 200000 |   0 |      20 |     0 |       140 |     0 |      2800 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 200000 |   0 |      30 |     0 |       130 |     0 |      3900 | lost   |
| 1000000 | 200000 |   0 |      40 |     0 |       120 |     0 |      4800 | lost   |
+---------+--------+-----+---------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Above an example of a quotation.
I need the percentage 'won' / 'quoted'
'quoted' is defined as the Value (EUR) or ValueAlt (EUR) for each Article_ID where the Qty or Qty_Alt has the maximum value.

In this example both articles 100000 and 200000 are quoted with max value of 40 pieces. The corresponding Values are 2800 + 4800 = 7600 EUR.

The percentage won I am looking for is therefore 100 * 2400 / 7600 = 31.6%

This code

```
"SELECT a.Quot_ID, (a.Value + a.Value_Alt) FROM Quotations a LEFT JOIN Quotations b ON a.Quot_ID = b.Quot_ID AND (a.Qty + a.Qty_Alt) < (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) WHERE (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) is NULL ORDER BY a.QuotationCode"
```

gives me

```
1000000 2800
1000000 4800
```

Does any one know how I can change this into one result:

```
1000000 7600
```

OK, Almost there:

Thanks to Muhammad I now have

> `SELECT a.Quot_ID, sum(a.Value + a.Value_Alt) FROM Quotations a LEFT JOIN Quotations b ON a.Quot_ID = b.Quot_ID AND (a.Qty + a.Qty_Alt) < (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) WHERE (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) is NULL GROUP BY a.Quot_ID ORDER BY a.Quot_ID`

Last step is to get the percentage 'won'

In this example 100 * 2400 / 7600 = 31,6%

Any ideas or hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Show your query with the Group By clause. Also mention what error you are getting.

Comment: What group by query give you error?

Comment: Have you tried this:     SELECT a.Quot_ID, sum(a.Value + a.Value_Alt) FROM Quotations a LEFT JOIN Quotations b ON a.Quot_ID = b.Quot_ID AND (a.Qty + a.Qty_Alt) < (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) WHERE (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) is NULL GROUP BY a.Quot_ID ORDER BY a.QuotationCode

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. That did it!. The solution is so simple,. I just overlooked it.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, nice work. Can you please move your solution to an answer so that Yafuhenk can accept it and put closure to this question?

Comment: @zedfoxus it is not completly solved, please see my comments in the orgional post

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Quot_ID, sum(a.Value + a.Value_Alt) , (a.Value_alt/(sum (a.value+a.value_alt))*100 as percentage FROM Quotations a LEFT JOIN Quotations b ON a.Quot_ID = b.Quot_ID AND (a.Qty + a.Qty_Alt) < (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) WHERE (b.Qty + b.Qty_Alt) is NULL GROUP BY a.Quot_ID ORDER BY a.QuotationCode
```